# There has been a critical error on this website. Get error without access to logs

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress is throwing a `There has been a critical error on this website.`

There are no plugins and the theme works fine on my local machine.

I am using cpanel and there are no server log files.

Is there a way to display the error.

Comment: Ask the hosting provider where the log files are located, there probably _are_ some, somewhere. Otherwise, [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could turn on WP Debug to allow WordPress show you what's breaking the website.

Locate the wp-config. php for your WordPress file, then click on the three-dotted options, then Edit. To Enable WP_Debug, change the last line to: define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ). To Disable WP_Debug, change the last line to: define( 'WP_DEBUG', false ).

Hope this helps!

Comment: WP Debug is on, but unfortunately it does not show critical errors.  These can only be found in the server logs.

Comment: Hmmm... 
Other things you could try:
1. Add these in wp-config.php to force errors to show:
`// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file`
`define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`

// Disable display of errors and warnings`
`define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );`
`@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );`

2. Check your cPanel or hosting server for PHP settings to allow for logging.

3. Try this WordPress logging plugin: [wordpress.org/plugins/wp-debugging]

Comment: yes I tried but it not work.